# Swift: Gregorian Calendar and weeks/weekdays - inconsistent behavior

Tags: swift, calendar

I need to get the current weekday as Int value, depending on the user's locale.

But when using the gregorian calendar with the current locale I realized an inconsistent behavior with the following code:

```
// Set calendar
var gregorian = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
// Use one of the two following locales:
gregorian?.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")
gregorian?.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "de_DE")
```

Then I have two cases:

```
// CASE 1: Give the calendar week number for today (in this case: May 10, 2015 which is a Sunday) 
// Expected result for US locale: CW 20, for some european locales e.g. DE/Germany: CW 19 due to first day of week = Monday)
var todayDateComps  = gregorian?.components(.CalendarUnitWeekOfYear, fromDate: NSDate())
println(todayDateComps)
```

So here the different locales work: CW 19 for german locale, CW 20 for US locale.

The issue is with the second case - the current Int weekday depending on user's locale:

```
// CASE 2: Give the numeric value for the weekday for today (in this case: May 10, 2015 which is a Sunday)
// Expected results: 1 for US locale, 7 for some european locales e.g. DE/Germany as Monday is first day of week
let comps = gregorian?.components(.CalendarUnitWeekday, fromDate: NSDate())
if let weekday = comps?.weekday {
   println(weekday)
}
```

The locale doesn't work here: Case 2 returns on both cases "1". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`weekday` is not locale-dependent. The property you are thinking of is `firstWeekday`.

Comment: yes, but this doesn't give me the int value of the current weekday

Comment: You mean, if you run this test on a Sunday you expect to see Monday, due to the time zone difference? Locales don't deal with time zones.

Comment: No, what I need is the int value of the current weekday depending on the NSLocale. So if today is Sunday, then I want for "en_US" returned "1" and for "de_DE" returned "7"

Comment: Sunday is always identified by 1, irrespective of the locale.

Comment: I updated the question to be clearer. Returning ALWAYS 1 for sunday and ignoring the calendar's local is inconsistent - that is what I mean in my question. Look at case 1 - here the locale is handled correctly by the calendar, it returns different week numbers for Sunday

Comment: That makes sense to me. Today is Sunday both in en_US and de_DE. So you get 1 (meaning Sunday) in any case. However the week starts on Sunday in en_US but on Sunday in de_DE, so the week of the year count is different, because today is the last day of the 19th week if you consider a week to be Monday->Sunday and the first day of the 20th week if you consider a week to be Sunday->Monday.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77447/discussion-between-clafou-and-pauli).

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution? I'm also trying to obtain 1 as Monday and not as Sunday...